# how to display only few options per line from database in php

Tags: php

I am fetching data from the database and displaying it in the table. I have applied a while loop before `<tr>` tag so it is showing each value in new line.

Now what i want is that it should show five values from database in each `<tr>` tag.
How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
     <body>
       <table border="2px;">

         <tr>
         <th>name</th>
         </tr>

        <?php
        $sql="select * from tb_transport";
           $query=mysql_query($sql);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
        ?>

          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
         </tr>
              <?php 

            } ?>
                 </table>
         </body>
```

Comment: oh sorry...i have edited my post

Comment: I didn't get this _in tag in each tag_??

Comment: you want 5 record in single row?

Comment: You want to stop the loop after 5 values are output?

Comment: yea @ajay...i want 5 record per line

Comment: @user3138522, five columns? five `<td>`? how about your title `<th>`? because there is only one `<th>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You need to start  on first record and close on last record of every row.

```
    <body>
           <table border="2px;">

             <tr>
             <th>name</th>
             </tr>

            <?php
            $sql="select * from tb_transport";
               $query=mysql_query($sql);

            $counter = 0;

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
              {
                 $counter++;
                 if($counter % 5 == 1)
                 {
                      ?><tr><?php
                 }
            ?>


                <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                <?php    
if($counter % 5 == 0)
                 {
                      ?></tr><?php
                 }



                } ?>
                     </table>
             </body>
```

Comment: our answer was helpful...thanx a lot

Comment: Nope, You just accept not upvoted. Pl click on up icon my friend.

Comment: based on the updated question, this answer is correct, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

to show 5 records per line use

if `($counter % 5 == 0)` inside your while loop;

```
     <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     </tr>

    <?php
    $sql="select * from tb_transport";
       $query=mysql_query($sql);
    $counter = 1; // set counter to 1
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
    ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php
                    if ($counter % 5 == 0)
                    echo $row["name"]; 
$counter++;
                    ?></td>
     </tr>
          <?php 

        } ?>
             </table>
     </body>
```

Comment: i did not get it there is only while loop

Comment: @user3138522 , I've updated the code, please review it

Comment: its not doing anything ??

Comment: @user3138522, please make sure you added the `#counter++` after the echo

Comment: i did not downvote your answer..i dont know did...anyways thanks for helping

Comment: Dear Down-Voters, @user3138522 in his 1st post (before editing it) he didn't mention he wants it in `<td>`, we provided this solution based on that. so don't hate the answer.

Comment: @sultan. I guess people dont like a fair fight, thats why they keep downvoting even the right answers

Comment: @user3138522, I know you didn't downvote it... but my msg was to the downvoter.  I glad you got an answer.

Comment: @sunny, yes I agree with you... We answer based on what we read.  Your answer and mine, is working 100% based on the provided information on the initial and 1st edit of the post.

Comment: @sultan, i am upvoting your answer, if you feel my answer was right, please upvote mine too

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
       <body>
           <table border="2px;">

             <tr>
             <th>name</th>
             </tr>

            <?php
            $sql="select * from tb_transport";
               $query=mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<tr>";
$number=1;
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
              {
            ?>


                <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
    <?php

                if ($number % 5 == 0)
    {    
    echo "</tr>"."<tr>";
    }  

                  <?php 
    $number++;
                } ?> 
    </tr>
                     </table>
             </body>
```

Comment: NEVER MIND! atleast, you got your answer, thats important .

Comment: I'm going to vote-up your answer, because your answer is correct based on the initial and 1st edit of the post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use counter variable,like.

```
<body>
  <table border="2px;">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $count=5;
      $sql="select * from tb_transport";
      $query=mysql_query($sql);
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
    ?>

        if($count == 5){ echo "<tr>"}

        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; 
        $counter--;
            ?></td>

        if($count == 1) { echo "</tr>";}
    <?php 
      } ?>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Same was done with me and sunny, we don't know why! Our answers met the requester requirements -with taking in care the provided information- BEFORE editing the question. but down-voters they just downvote answers without even checking what was the initial post! I am going to upvote your answer.

Comment: ok thanks, my intents is not copy your answer but when I write answer you already post it .

Comment: That happens a lot, we answer at the same time with few minutes differences.  It does NOT mean you or I copied other answers.  Anyway, please upvote my answer because I feel downvoting it unfair based on the circumstances.